# Difference between "oreja" and "oído"

Tags: significado, diferencias-entre-palabras, cuerpo-humano

What is the difference between 'oreja' and 'oído'?

Both mean ear, no?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Oído:** the whole organ or organs of hearing
**Oreja:** just the "external ear".

This is the definition of ear according to the Webster dictionary:

> **ear** noun \ˈir\
> **Definition of EAR**
> **1 a :** the characteristic vertebrate organ of hearing and equilibrium consisting in the typical mammal of a sound-collecting outer ear separated by the tympanic membrane from a sound-transmitting middle ear that in turn is > separated from a sensory inner ear by membranous fenestrae
> **b :** any of various organs (as of a fish) capable of detecting vibratory motion
>
> **2:** the external ear of humans and most mammals
> [...]

According to this, oído refers to definition 1, and oreja to definition 2.

Comment: "oído" can also be the sense of hearing.

Comment: @Javi: Yes, and it's also the participle of oír, and something about firearms and explosives. But regarding the difference between *oído* and *oreja*, I think the anatomical meanings are just enough. By the way, *oreja* also means "sentido de la audición", so in that meaning they're just the same.

Comment: RAE can say they are the same, but at least in Spain people uses only "oído" for that meaning. "Los cinco sentidos son vista, olfato, gusto, tacto y oído".

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but it feels weird to me to use "oreja" meaning the sense of hearing...

Answer (score 2):

The *oído* is related to hearing and the inner ear (*mis oídos te escuchan*); the *oreja* is the external ear (*la oreja de Van Gogh*).

Comment: Welcome, David.  This answer is a bit minimalist and redundant, I suppose, but I think the mnemonic, *la oreja de Van Gogh*, could be helpful for people.