# ¿Se usa o ha usado en algún momento "oreja" para referirse al sentido de la audición?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, historia

Viendo algunas preguntas del sitio, cierta vez solicitó alguien la [distinción entre oído y oreja](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/difference-between-oreja-and-o%C3%ADdo). Entre los comentarios se destacaba que *Oreja* hace referencia al sentido de la audición, lo que me llamó la atención pues nunca lo había escuchado de esa forma. Si bien el mapa de diccionarios ya lo incluye como oído o la acción de oír en 1780, en 1884 se tiene como significado oído, para un siglo después (1992) redefinirlo como sentido de la audición hasta hoy. No sé si es un localismo ibérico o una forma que se encuentra en desuso, pero ¿Se usa ese significado en la actualidad? ¿De qué forma se usa o se usó? (Una frase del estilo 'sentido de la oreja'... la verdad no me suena)

Comment: Podría ser por expresiones como "pegar la oreja", "aguzar las orejas" o "parar la oreja" ("prestar atención"), o "taparse las orejas" ("dejar de escuchar").

Comment: No es que oreja sea sinónimo de oír, pero en Colombia usamos mucho la frase "parar oreja" Ej: "Ponga atención" = "Pare oreja" = "Escuche atentamente"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión *aguzar las orejas* es tan antigua como el propio idioma español. Lo mismo te la encuentras en el siglo XIII que en el XXI. Al principio parece que se usaba para los caballos (y seguramente otros animales):

> *Ya se movién las hazes, ívanse allegando,
>
>   ivan los ballesteros las saetas tirando,
>
>   ivan los cavalleros las lanças abaxando
>
>   e ivan los cavallos orejas aguzando.*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro de Alexandre", 1240-1250 (España).

La idea original era usar el verbo *aguzar*, ya registrado en diccionarios del siglo XV, con el sentido de "sacar punta", "afilar", usado en este caso para indicar que el caballo puso las orejas en punta, cosa que hacen cuando están atendiendo a los sonidos externos.

Hoy día la expresión se usa para cualquiera:

> *Mi afán de humanista más que mi oficio de cronista me ha hecho aguzar mis orejas para oír lo que las gentes decían, no siempre lo que pensaban.*
>
> Antonio Beltrán Martínez, "Pueblos de Aragón II", 2000 (España).

Queda claro que en este caso con *orejas* se refiere al sentido del oído.